# Draw inside a table cell

Tags: sapui5

I want to create a very simple stacked bar inside a table cell.

I don't need any annotations or axes, just some stacked squares.
I was thinking of using the HTML5 canvas `stroke` options for this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_rect

Can this be done by getting a reference to the cell, getting its size and use the `stroke` method on the context of this cell?

Answer (score 0):

Getting a reference and just adding plain html usually is not a good idea. Controls might get rerendered and esp. the Table dynamically manages rows and columns (it reuses rows while scrolling/paging).

For easy html-embedding you can just type it right away in a XMLView or use [`sap.ui.core.HTML`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.HTML.html).

For more complex content you better create a [notepad control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f1703b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) and create you custom content in a custom renderer. If you just use JS for content creation then just create an empty div in the renderer do your stuff in onAfterRendering and attach your created html into this div. This way UI5 will have full control and everything around your custom control should work just fine.

BR
Chris